# Error in generator$render using serve_site in R Blogdown

Tags: r, blogdown

When I open my R Studio blogdown project and `serve_site()` it previews in the viewer and seems fine except that the content is not updated as it is in .Rmd files. It seems as though the preview site is getting stuck on the old .html files.

When *saving* an edited blogdown post in R Studio after executing `serve_site()` I expect the live preview to update.

Right now however, if I make a small edit to a post and click save, the preview fails and I get the following error that I can't make sense of or fix:

```
Error in generator$render(input_file = input_file, output_format = output_format,  : 
  You probably should not knit the document in a blogdown project. Just call blogdown::serve_site() once per R session. See https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/workflow.html. If you are sure you want to knit it and know what it means, set options(blogdown.allow_knit = TRUE).
Calls: <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.14.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.2.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.0        compiler_3.4.3    later_0.8.0       prettyunits_1.0.2 remotes_2.0.2    
 [6] tools_3.4.3       testthat_2.0.1    digest_0.6.18     pkgbuild_1.0.2    pkgload_1.0.2    
[11] jsonlite_1.6      evaluate_0.13     memoise_1.1.0     rlang_0.3.1       rstudioapi_0.9.0 
[16] cli_1.0.1         curl_3.3          yaml_2.2.0        blogdown_0.10.5   xfun_0.4         
[21] stringr_1.4.0     withr_2.1.2       knitr_1.21        desc_1.2.0        fs_1.2.6         
[26] devtools_2.0.1    rprojroot_1.3-2   glue_1.3.0        R6_2.4.0          processx_3.2.1   
[31] rmarkdown_1.11    bookdown_0.9      sessioninfo_1.1.1 servr_0.12        callr_3.1.1      
[36] magrittr_1.5      backports_1.1.2   ps_1.3.0          promises_1.0.1    htmltools_0.3.6  
[41] usethis_1.4.0     rsconnect_0.8.13  assertthat_0.2.0  xtable_1.8-3      mime_0.6         
[46] httpuv_1.4.5.1    stringi_1.3.1     miniUI_0.1.1.1    crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: Try to uncheck the two options as shown in Figure 1.8 in the **blogdown** book, restart RStudio, run `blogdown::serve_site()`, and see if that helps: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/rstudio-ide.html

Comment: That seems to have worked once but I restarted R again and now I have this error: ```Error: Error building site: template: __072dc17e293bb5e606a28f920aaa48fe:127: unexpected "&" in command
To stop the server, run servr::daemon_stop(1) or restart your R session
Serving the directory /Users...```

Comment: I don't know what that error means. You may try a newer version of RStudio: https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/

Comment: Updating my version of R worked, for the record.